# Java DecimalFormat get Pattern as text

Tags: java, formatting

I have a case where I would like to create a `DecimalFormat` by setting various options directly. For example,

```
pattern.setNegativePrefix(myPrefix);
pattern.setNegativeSuffif(mySuffix);
pattern.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
```

etc. But when all's said and done, I'd like to actually capture the pattern string that represents that so I can reuse it again. Can I do that using this method or do I have to construct the pattern string myself and pass it in?

In other words, I'm asking, is there an equivalent to the (non-existent) `getPattern` method in `DecimalFormat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`toPattern()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#toPattern%28%29).

> Synthesizes a pattern string that represents the current state of this Format object.

```
String text = pattern.toPattern();
```

Comment: Yikes! I must be having a slow day. Thanks.